# Cassandra - Dropped MUTATION_RSP and READ_RSP

Tags: cassandra

It does looks load related, should I increase the

native_transport_max_threads: 128 to 256?

Message type: READ_RSP

Dropped: 38320

50%: 1131.752

95%: 2816.159

99%: 7007.506

Max: 155469.30000000002

---

Message type: MUTATION_RSP

Dropped: 340577

50%: 36157.19

95%: 107964.792

99%: 107964.792

Max: 962624.926